# Improved a closed question to answer it, but it wasn't re-opened. What next?

Tags: discussion

I edited [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518900/what-is-rate-distortion-theory-and-why-is-mutual-information-minimized-in-the-ra) to make it more general and to be more clear about what the OP was asking. I also edited it so that I can provide a brief overview of what rate distortion theory is and to answer the question in detail. My edit was approved, but the question wasn't re-opened. I've already prepared a detailed answer, but I can't post it since the question wasn't re-opened. I also don't want to post a similar question with my own answer to avoid a duplicate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It was closed only three hours ago, so some patience is needed. People following the queues know it can typically take two days or more, since too few people contribute. I have reopened it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some clarification about how SE works:

- Editing a question doesn't automatically re-open it; it populates the review queue where reviewers will vote to reopen it or not. Not everyone who participates in the review queues understands the details of every question in the queue, so it can take time for enough votes to reopen a quesiton.
- A new question can't be closed as a duplicate of a question with 0 answers. (Except by a moderator; this exception is rarely utilized. It is generally only used for the case of a user repeatedly posting the same question over and over again.)

My advice is to wait a day. If the question isn't reopened in the next 24 hours, you can post your question & answer. If you like, you could even post a comment on the closed question linking to your question and answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!